# Understanding Rubi's result in light of MMA's Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I've been experimenting/playing with the Rubi 4.14.1 package for MMA, see [here](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/%7Earich/).  Unfortunately I have not been able to find too much documentation.

For the following function of `c` I was surprised MMA returned an answer, while Rubi returned... well I don't quite know how to interpret what was produced.  I'd appreciate any light you can shed

```
fc = -(1/2) Erf[((2 m - k^2) - 2 Log[c + b] + 2 Log[a])/(2 Sqrt[2] k)] - 1/2 
fcresmma = 
 Assuming[m \[Element] Reals && k > 0 && c >= 0 && a > 0 && b > 0, 
  Integrate[fc, c]]

fcres = Assuming[
  m \[Element] Reals && k > 0 && c >= 0 && a > 0 && b > 0, Int[fc, c]]
```

The MMA (11.2) results is

```
1/2 (-c - (b + c) Erf[(-k^2 + 2 m + 2 Log[a] - 2 Log[b + c])/( 2 Sqrt[2] k)] + 
a E^m Erf[(k^2 + 2 m + 2 Log[a] - 2 Log[b + c])/(2 Sqrt[2] k)])
```

The Rubi result is:

```
-(c/2) - Dist[1/2, Subst[ Int[ Erf[
       (-k^2 (1 - (2 (m + Log[a]))/k^2) - 2 Log[c])/(2 Sqrt[2] k)
], c], c, b + c], c]
```

**Update: Confirmed and Resolved in Rubi 4.14.3**

> ... Rubi 4.14.3 is able to integrate any expression of this form including when m is 0, numeric or symbolic.  In fact, it can integrate any expression of the form
>
> (e x)^m F[d (a+b log(c x^n))]
>
> where F is Erf, Erfc, Erfi, FresnelS, FresnelC, ExpIntegralEi, SinIntegral, CosIntegral, SinhIntegral, CoshIntegral or Gamma (incomplete).

Comment: Rubi can now integrate this.  I'm guessing you made Albert Rich aware of this, and he then added the needed rule.

Comment: Also, note that there's no point in using Assuming w/ Rubi, since it's not designed to accept domain restrictions, and is thus unaffected by them (you can test this yourself).  According to Albert Rich, "The antiderivatives Rubi produces are valid throughout the complex plane.  That is the derivative of the antiderivative equals the integrand for all real and complex values of the integration variable and the integrand’s parameters...Rubi does not make use of domain restriction assumptions other than Mathematica’s use of them to simplify expressions Rubi sees or produces."

Comment: @theorist: Thanks I'd lost track of this. Updated the question to show the status

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When Rubi return `Dist` and `Subts` calls in its final output, it means it has no rules for this part.

This is assuming you already  did

```
 ShowSteps = False;
```

At the start before calling `Int`.  Otherwise Rubi will show only one step at a time, waiting for user to evaluate the last output manually.

But in this case, Rubi just did not have a rule to complete this integration.

```
 ClearAll[m,c,k,a,b]
 fc=-(1/2) Erf[((2 m-k^2)-2 Log[c+b]+2 Log[a])/(2 Sqrt[2] k)]-1/2;
 ShowSteps = False;
 Int[fc,c]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To see the actual rules invoked, you can do use this function, by Albert Rich

```
StepInt[u_,x_Symbol]:=Block[{ShowSteps=True},
   FixedPoint[Function[Print[#];
   ReplaceAll[#,{Defer[Int]->Int,Defer[Dist]->Dist,
       Defer[Subst]->Subst}]],Int[u,x]];
   Null]
```

And now you call it as follows

```
  StepInt[fc,c]
```

It will display the rule numbers used in each internal step

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So Rubi did not know how to integrate the `Erf` in there.

Comment: Is there any etiquette around reporting these examples? Do you know where or how?

Comment: @Hedgehog You could either contact Albert Rich, the Author of Rubi directly via email, or sometimes I just post questions about Rubi at sci.math.symbolic  (which you can access via google groups also). Albert reads that news group as well.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sci.math.symbolic

Comment: Thanks @Nasser.  Apologies for not getting back - got swamped.  Your contact suggestions resulted in a fix released in Rubi 4.14.3

Comment: @Hedgehog fyi, Rubi current version is 4.14.8. Latest intergation tests are [here](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/CAS_integration_tests/index.htm)